# VB.NET / .NET 4.8: Syntax error insert into statement ... ALSO USER ID IF LEFT OUT KEEPS TELLING ME MISSING VALUE VISUAL STUDIO 2022

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class MainForm

Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim myread As OleDbCommand
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn.ConnectionString =          "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\ISIOLO.accdb"

End Sub

Private Sub BtnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCreate.Click
    conn.Open()
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USERS(EMAIL,PASSWORD,DESIGNATION)     VALUES(@Email,@Password,@Designation)"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TxtEmail.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TxtPassword.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", ComboDesignation.Text)

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText)
        For Each parameter As OleDbParameter In cmd.Parameters
            Console.WriteLine($"{parameter.ParameterName}: {parameter.Value}")
        Next
        conn.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("successful")
        PnlCreateAccount.Visible = False


    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        conn.Close()

    End Try
 End Sub
 End Class
```

ADD user into access TABLE - it has four columns:

```
USERID
EMAIL TEXT
PASSWORD  TEXT
DESIGNATION  TEXT
```

`USER ID` is auto-increment, can't seem to want to be left out

Comment: Does the sql work when run directly against the database?

Comment: Please edit your post to stop with the all-caps - it's widely regarded as equivalent to shouting.

Comment: Could you please put the error in the question. I suspect the UserID is NOT auto-increment or you're connecting to a different db.

Comment: ALthough it's MS Access, to make a habit of it, consider using [```.Parameters.Add``` instead of ```.Parameters.AddWithValue```](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Answer (score 3):

"Password" is a reserved word in Jet/ACE SQL, so you need to escape it when using it as an identifier:

```vb
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USERS (EMAIL, [PASSWORD], DESIGNATION) VALUES (@Email, @Password, @Designation)"
```

Ideally, you should not be storing passwords in the database directly, but rather hashing them. You can then reasonably name your column `PasswordHash` and avoid the issue altogether.